# Override YSOD for errors in that occur before Render() in page lifecycle and then write the exception contents as HTML comment for that control

Tags: c#, asp.net, error-handling, sitecore

I'm trying to figure out a way to capture all exceptions of a specific type that occur before the `Render()` method in the page lifecycle, store them and bypass the YSOD error handler. Then in an override of `Render()` do something like this:

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if(ReqObjectException != null)
    {
        base.Render(writer);
    }
    else
    {
        Log.Error("Missing required object in Base Control", ReqObjectException, this);
        writer.WriteLine("<!--");
        foreach(var exception in ReqObjectExceptions)
        {
            writer.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
        writer.WriteLine("-->");
    }
}
```

The idea here is that I have some dynamic controls that are added to a page and they occasionally required to have some data associated with them. Right now, if a content author forgets to attach the associated data, they get a YSOD and freak out. 
The idea here is that the rest of the page continues to function, and there is a log entry and an HTML comment pointing to the problem. Maybe I'll create some warning dialog to let them know that there is something missing.

Comment: In case you're using ASP.NET MVC, you normally would do something like that in the Application_Error() method in your Global.asax. That should also work for a single rendering in Sitecore.

Comment: I'm not working in MVC right now, but I will be eventually so the same type of functionality will be useful there.

Comment: http://www.sitecore.net/learn/blogs/technical-blogs/john-west-sitecore-blog/posts/2011/05/trap-sublayout-exceptions-in-the-sitecore-aspnet-cms.aspx <-- you trying to do something similar to how xslt renderings are handled by sitecore? this might lead you in right direction.

Comment: For Sitecore MVC there is a blog by Charlie Tourano on how to implement this kind of handling. https://www.hhogdev.com/blog/2015/june/mvc-rendering-exception-handler.aspx I guess it can help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to nsgocev for the MVC implementation, it put me on the right track.

With Web Forms the same type of thing doesn't work. Luckily all of the our Sublayouts don't perform their logic directly in Page_Init or Page_Load. The base Sublayout has the following methods:

```
protected virtual void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.Initialize();      
}

protected virtual void Initialize()
{
    this.Bind();
}

protected virtual void Bind()
{
}
```

The derived Sublayouts perform all of their logic in Bind() or Initialize(). I wrapped the Initialize in Page_Init with a try catch and added a class property called Exeption.

```
protected virtual void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (CommonConfig.SuppressRenderingExceptions)
    {
        try
        {
            this.Initialize();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Exception = ex;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        this.Initialize();
    }
}
```

I then overrode Render()

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    if (this.Exception == null)
    {
        try
        {
            base.Render(writer);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            this.Exception = ex;
        }
    }

    if (this.Exception != null)
    {
        writer.BeginRender();
        MRenderingManager.HandleRenderingException(writer, this.Exception, this.BaseTypeName, this);
        writer.EndRender();
    }
}
```

If there is an exception, either in the Page_Init or base.Render() then the we execute HandleRenderingException().

```
public static void HandleRenderingException(TextWriter writer, Exception ex, string baseTypeName, object owner)
{
    Log.Error("Rendering Error", ex, owner);

    if (Context.PageMode.IsNormal)
    {
        writer.WriteLine("<!--");
        writer.WriteLine("[Your comment or serialized exception]");
        writer.WriteLine("-->");
    }
    else
    {
        writer.WriteLine("<div class=\"rendering-exception\">");
        writer.WriteLine("[Your comment or serialized exception]");
        writer.WriteLine("</div>");
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Server.ClearError();
}
```

This way, content authors will get a helpful message in Page Editor/Preview mode if they add a broken control.